# What is an "operator int" function?

Tags: c++, terminology, conversion-operator

What is the "operator int" function below? What does it do?

```
class INT
{
   int a;

public:
   INT(int ix = 0)
   {
      a = ix;
   }

   /* Starting here: */
   operator int()
   {
      return a;
   }
   /* End */

   INT operator ++(int)
   {
      return a++;
   }
};
```

Comment: What bold code ? Otherwise it's basically a wrapper for `int` with conversion to `int` and operator `++`.

Comment: Looking at the source of the original post, `operator int()` is supposed to be the bold code.

Comment: If I could, I would honestly vote to re-open this. The original question was formatted poorly but had a segment of code clearly in bold. A later edit (not by the OP) was what made the code un-bold and hence made the question seem incoherent.

Comment: @All : I am the culprit here. Voted to reopen.

Comment: It solves the halting problem ;)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The bolded code is a conversion operator. (AKA [cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cast-operator-parens?view=msvc-170))

It gives you a way to convert from your custom `INT` type to another type (in this case, `int`) without having to call a special conversion function explicitly.

For example, with the convert operator, this code will compile:

```
INT i(1234);
int i_2 = i; // this will implicitly call INT::operator int()
```

Without the convert operator, the above code won't compile, and you would have to do something else to go from an `INT` to an `int`, such as:

```
INT i(1234);
int i_2 = i.a;  // this wont compile because a is private
```

Comment: Broken cast operator link; can you try to find the new one please?

Comment: Interesting sidenote: conversion operators are the only functions that will resolve based on the return type. This allows all sorts of cool tricks that most people believe are impossible.

Comment: Also, conversion operators can cause weird quirks occasionally. Prefer to mark them `explicit` whenever possible/reasonable.

Answer (score 18):

`operator int()` is a *conversion operator*, which allows this class to be used in place of an `int`. If an object of this type is used in a place where an `int` (or other numerical type) is expected, then this code will be used to get a value of the correct type.

For example:

```
int i(1);
INT I(2); // Initialised with constructor; I.a == 2
i = I;    // I is converted to an int using `operator int()`, returning 2.
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation for this on cppreference.com. Can you?

Answer (score 6):

First things first:

> $12.3.1/1 - "A constructor declared
>   without the function-specifier
>   explicit specifies a conversion from
>   the types of its parameters to the
>   type of its class. Such a constructor
>   is called a converting constructor."

In your example, INT is a User Defined class that has a converting constructor from 'int'.

Therefore the following code is well-formed:

```
INT i(1024);     // direct initialization syntax
```

This means that you can get an INT object from an integer. However what does one do, if the INT object has to be converted back to an integer? Transitivity?

One can say that the class INT can provide a member function to return the encapsulated integer member

```
int x = i.geta();
```

This however is not very intuitive and is not a standardized approach. Also it is not intuitive when it comes to how built-in types work in such situations.

```
int z = 0;
int y1 = z; // copy initialization or
int y2(z);  // direct initialization
double d = (int )z; // explicit cast
```

Therefor the Standard allows for such standardization and intuitiveness of converting User Defined Types by saying:

> $12.3/2 - "A member function of a
>   class X having no parameters with a
>   name of the form [...]
>
> **operator conversion-type-id**
>
> [...]specifies a conversion from X to the
>   type specified by the
>   conversion-type-id. Such functions are
>   called conversion functions. No return
>   type can be specified. If a conversion
>   function is a member function, the
>   type of the conversion function
>   (8.3.5) is “function taking no
>   parameter returning
>   conversion-type-id”.

This makes all of the following well-formed and **retains harmony with the way built-in types work** is

```
int y1 = i; // copy initialization or
int y2(i);  // direct initialization
double d = (int )i; // explicit cast
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it make an INT class which behaves a little like the regular int, just that some other operators are not yet defined.

Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's a question from a classroom, so I'll invite you to check the documentation on how to create a class.

```
class Foo
{
public
    Foo() {} // Constructor

    Foo operator++ {} // Operation ++ on foo like:
    // Foo foo;
    // foo++;
};
```