# C++ bracket operator for castable types

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

Setup.

```
enum class A { ... };
std::vector<B> bs;
A a = A::foo;
bs[a].bar(); // not going to compile, A isn't an integer
```

I want to be able to write this as it is very convenient. The easiest way I see is to write a free function bracket overload operator.

```
template<class T> inline constexpr
underlying_type_t<T> underlying_cast(T t)
{ return static_cast<underlying_type_t<T>>(t); }

B& operator[](std::vector<B>& b, A a)
{ return b[underlying_cast(a)]; }
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Look at this. Should work I'm not sure, never tried.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814865/what-is-an-operator-int-function

Comment: I guess `bs[static_cast<int>(a)]` is too verbose. If you want an enum that implicitly converts to an `int` you could use an old enum `enum A { foo };`. I mean there is no need to prevent implicit conversions when this is what you want to use it for

Comment: There may be a good reason to want a vector indexed by an enum without allowing the enum to implicitly convert to an `int` everywhere.  Ada has a nice (built-in) language feature of being able to specify the index type for an array, and I've sometimes wished that C++ had a similar feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot overload `operator[]` outside the class definition.  If you want an overload that takes an argument of the enum `A`, you have to define a subclass of `std::vector` and add the overload within the subclass.

Example:

```
#include <vector>

template<class Enum, class Val>
class VectorByEnum : public std::vector<Val>
{
public:
    using std::vector<Val>::vector; // inherit constructors

    Val & operator[](Enum idx)
    {
        typedef typename VectorByEnum::size_type idx_t;
        return std::vector<Val>::operator[](static_cast<idx_t>(idx));
    }
};

enum class A {
    One,
    Two
};

class B
{
public:
    int bar() { return 0; }
};

int main(void)
{
    VectorByEnum<A, B> v(2);
    return v[A::Two].bar();
}
```

Comment: this is probably the best we can do but all operators should be capable of free function overriding